# Salt execution-module cannot read pillar data

Tags: python, salt-stack

I am very new to salt and I have the following set up -- still in progress:

- pillar data (containing a dictionary to specify application environments)
- execution module setup.py containing functions to read out the pillar

It works fine when calling the module on the minion minion1

```
salt-call setup.set_up_minion1 --log-level=debug
```

It doesn't work when calling the module on the master

```
salt 'minion1' setup.set_up_minion1 --log-level=debug
```

The error is

```
The minion function caused an exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/minion.py", line 1071, in _thread_return
    return_data = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/cache/salt/minion/extmods/modules/setup.py", line 38, in set_up_minion1
    environment_definition = __pillar__["minion1"]
KeyError: 'minion1'
```

The code line mentioned in the error message is

```
  environment_definition = __pillar__["minion1"]
```

As you can see in the error message, salt cannot find the "minion1" key in the pillar. I have no idea what is happening and why ...

I tested the content of the pillar from the server:

```
salt '*1*' pillar.items
```

returns

```
minion1.mydomain.nope:
----------
minion1:
    ----------
    app_server_definition:
        minion1_app
    db_server_definition:
        minion1_db
<snip>
```

and from the minion:

```
salt-call pillar.items
```

returns

```
local:
----------
minion1:
    ----------
    app_server_definition:
        minion1_app
    db_server_definition:
        minion1_db
<snip>
```

Can anyone please explain me what is happening and why I cannot call the execution module from the server? Thank you.

Comment: is there a reason why you want to write an execution module - usually you write states - most common tasks are covered by the states available in salt by default. your own execution modules are only required for very special stuff.

Comment: The reason for it is because we have many servers for different clients and I don't want to accidentally mess up an existing configuration just because there was "*' in the salt command for the minions. The other reason is the pillar is defined in an abstract way, so I can configure environments pretty neatly and without duplicating values like username, groupname, password -- these have to be on the other side sometimes overridden by custom values -- but therefore to figure out how an environment is configured, I'm parsing the pillar using python. Everything else would be very tedious.

Comment: you can achieve this with states and pillar, too. have a look at the [salt formulas](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas) which are usually configurable through pillar data. the top.sls applies the states (or formulas) to your minion and highstate does the rest for you. we are fine with this setup and there were no accidents in the past year.

Comment: This is odd. Is there anywhere in your module where you're modifying __pillar__ ?